Как изменить локаль приложения laravel в тестах?
Коллеги подскажите пожалуйста как можно изменить локаль приложения в тестах? Я пробовал через сессии, метод setLocale и через фасад Config, но безрезультатно - локаль остается дефолтной.
    public function test_localize_en_message(): void
    {
        App::setLocale('en');
        $user = User::factory()->create();

        $response = $this->post('/api/auth/otp', [
            'email' => $user->email,
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertExactJson(['message' => 'The OTP-Code has been sent to your email.']);
    }


Попробуйте через .env.testing, который по можно использовать для phpunit тестов, выставив там APP_LOCALE. Хотя по факту данные оттуда будут попадать в config, не уверен что это поможет ...
